# How to configure Jenkins for php coverage report?

Tags: php, symfony1, jenkins, code-coverage

I am struggling to set up the code coverage.
What must i do, how do i set this up so i can get a coverage map/report please?

I have a unit test that runs. What checkboxes must i check under: Post-build actions?
Must i install a plugin? The unit test is in php 5.3.2 and i run symfony 1.4.5

in cibuild script i run:

```
php "test/unit/RbcTest.php"
```

and here the actual test code:

```
<?php
  require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../bootstrap/unit.php';
  require_once 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Autoload.php';
  set_include_path ('phoenix/lib/');
  $coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage;
  $coverage->start('strtolowerTest.php');
  $coverage->stop();
  $writer = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover;
  $writer->process($coverage, 'phoenix/test/clover.xml');
  $writer = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML;
  $writer->process($coverage, 'phoenix/test/code-coverage-report');
?>

<?php //strtolowerTest.php
echo "1. for strlower";
require_once 'phoenix/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/lime/lime.php';
echo "2. for strlower";
require_once 'phoenix/lib/validator/myValidatorString.class.php';
echo "3. for strlower";
require_once 'phoenix/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/validator/sfValidatorString.class.php';
$t = new lime_test(2,  new lime_output_color());
$t->is(myValidatorString::doCleanEmail('blabla-32.mtmail..com'), 'blabla@mtmail.com');
$t->is(myValidatorString::doClean('@#*+??%^!~blabla-===32.mtmail..com'), 'blabla@mtmail.com');
$t->is(myValidatorString::slugify('sensio   labs'), 'sensio-labs');
$t->is(myValidatorString::slugify('paris,france'), 'paris-france');
$t->is(myValidatorString::slugify('  sensio'), 'sensio');
$t->is(myValidatorString::slugify('sensio  '), 'sensio');
$t->is(myValidatorString::slugify(''), 'n-a', '::slugify() converts the empty string to n-a');
$t->is(myValidatorString::slugify(' - '), 'n-a', '::slugify() converts a string that only contains non-ASCII characters to n-a');

$t->diag('hello world');
$t->ok(true, 'test something');
?>
```

please help
thanks

Here are the output when i view the console build in jenkins:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Class test/phpunit/unit/RbcTest could not be found in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/phpunit/unit/RbcTest.php.Publishing Clover coverage report...
Publishing Clover HTML report...
Publishing Clover XML report...
Publishing Clover coverage results...
Code coverage enforcement failed for the following metrics:
    Methods
    Conditionals
Setting Build to unstable.
Build step 'Publish Clover Coverage Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Publishing Clover XML report...
Publishing Clover coverage results...
Code coverage enforcement failed for the following metrics:
    Methods
Setting Build to unstable.
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Build result
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Increased number of failed tests
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Increased number of passed tests
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Decreased number of failed tests
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Decreased number of passed tests
[ci-game] evaluating rule: PMD violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: pylint violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: CPD violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Checkstyle violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: FindBugs violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: FXCop violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Simian violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: StyleCop violation
[ci-game] evaluating rule: HIGH priority PMD warnings
[ci-game] evaluating rule: NORMAL priority PMD warnings
[ci-game] evaluating rule: LOW priority PMD warnings
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Changed number of compiler warnings
[ci-game] evaluating rule: Changed number of checkstyle warnings
Finished: UNSTABLE



 <?php
 class myValidatorString extends sfValidatorString
 {
    static public function slugify($text)
   {
       echo "in myvalidatorstring for class sfValidatorString.class.php";
       // replace all non letters or digits by -
       $text = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $text);

       // trim and lowercase
       $text = strtolower(trim($text, '-'));

       if (empty($text))
       {
        return 'n-a';
       }
       return $text;
   }
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP by itself does not generate code coverage information. The [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension will collect which lines are executed while a script runs, but it won't create reports. You should use [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) with [PHP_CodeCoverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage) to run your tests and output the report that Jenkins can make available.

Use `pecl` to install Xdebug and `pear` for the other two. You should also take a look at [Template for Jenkins Jobs for PHP Projects](http://jenkins-php.org/).

Comment: thanks you,installed PHP_CodeCoverage. where do i go from here please? what is the next step to get my jenkins to produce a code coverage report? thanks

Comment: Install PHPUnit and follow the [docs](www.phpunit.de) for setting up CC. You'll need to write your unit tests for it, or you can try to use CC without it. I haven't done that, though.

Comment: thank you i have unit tests and have PHPUnit installed. i configured jenkins to generate the clover.xml but no matter how i define the path, it gives errors! Please see main post for the error messages

Comment: Jenkins won't generate `clover.xml`--PHP_CodeCoverage will. Please paste the console output from the build so we can see what your build script does.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to get a coverage report but it now has a status of unstable. i post the console output in the the main post :)

Comment: Notice the error message `Class test/phpunit/unit/RbcTest could not be found in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/phpunit/unit/RbcTest.php.` Did you rewrite your unit tests using PHPUnit? It's very particular about how test cases must be written.

Comment: thank you i noticed it, but what do you mean i have to write my tests using PHPUnit? in one of my tests i have: class myValidatorString extends sfValidatorString and the latter is in another directory: phoenix/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/validator/sfValidatorString.class.php how can i get my test to access that class? i will post my test in the main post. thank you :)

Comment: PHPUnit runs a file named `bootstrap.php` in the current directory by default. This is where you set the include path and any autoloading you need to locate your classes. I would get it running outside of Jenkins first to remove variables. Follow the docs for PHPUnit. Explaining it all in comments is not the best way.

Comment: thank you, I am running my test from my commandline and i checked for the file and found it in phoenix/plugins/sfFormExtraPlugin/test/bootstrap.php. i added the line: require_once $_SERVER['SYMFONY'].'phoenix/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/validator'; and it still cannot find my class. i dont understand. should i move the bootstrap.php? thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symfony or your project, but the [PHPUnit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/index.html) describes all the steps necessary to set up unit tests and `bootstrap.php`.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, you can use the [Clover PHP plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clover+PHP+Plugin). After installing that plugin, you'll have additional job configuration options to set everything up (see the description of the plugin).

Comment: i ran wget http://myhost.net:12343/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar and have the file now. next i do: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myhost.net:1234 install-plugin cloverphp and get: Invalid or corrupt jarfile jenkins-cli.jar ??? pleas help? thank you!

Comment: You can install plugins through the web interface. Just go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins.